# Looping through an array and look for repeating numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays

Ok, I've spent almost two days on this problem and I give up.

What I'm trying to do is create an array of random numbers between 0-17, where each number will repeat once - so 36 numbers in total.

I wrote a function to check how many times a number occurs, if it's twice, then it returns false.

It works up until I get an undefined number, then it breaks...

Here's what I have:

```
var numbers = [];

    function checkNumberRepeat(n,o,c){
        var count = 0;
        for(var i in o){
            if(o[i] == n){
                count ++;
            }
        }
        if(count == c){

            return false;
        }else{
            return n;   
        }
    }

    function makeRand(){
        var rand = checkNumberRepeat(Math.floor(Math.random()*18),numbers,2);

        if(rand){
            return rand;
        }else{
            makeRand();
        }   
    }


    for(var i=0;i<36;i++){  
        numbers.push(makeRand());
        console.log(numbers);
    }
```

I'm pretty sure the problem is happening in my myRand() function

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Sidenote: use the `array.forEach()`.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing return

```
return makeRand()
```

It has no return so returns undefined

**UPDATE:**

you had another mistake in your code. 0 is falsy so the `if (rand)` when rand is 0 returns false, hence 0 is never inserted => endless loop

makeRand shoul like this:

```
function makeRand() {
    var rand = checkNumberRepeat(Math.floor(Math.random()*18),numbers,2);

    if (rand !== false){
        return rand;
    } else {
        return makeRand();
    }   
}
```

**updated** jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nayish/c9sk9suc/4/

Comment: I'm getting an error: too much recursion
 

for(var i in o){

Comment: This is because  youre using a recursion which is not the best option for this since by the end of the array it can take a very long time to finish and run out of memory

Comment: @flyagaricus Found another mistake,,, now the code works... still, not the best way to do this sort of thing

Comment: 0==false... but remember to use === or youll have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

I would take a different approach.

Create an array of `[0,0,1,1,2,2,...17,17]`:

```
var numbers = [];

for(var i = 0 ; i <= 17 ; i++) {
  numbers.push(i);
  numbers.push(i);
}
```

Iterate through the array, swapping the current element with a random element:

```
for(var i = 0 ; i < numbers.length ; i++) {
  var rnd= Math.floor(Math.random()*numbers.length),
      tmp= numbers[rnd];

  numbers[rnd]= numbers[i];
  numbers[i]= tmp;
}
```

[**Fiddle 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/5up1jvpm/)

---

This could easily be made into a function:

```
function randomize(start, stop, count) {
  var numbers = [];

  for(var i = start ; i <= stop ; i++) {
    for(var j = 0 ; j < count ; j++) {
      numbers.push(i);
    }
  }

  for(var i = 0 ; i < numbers.length ; i++) {
    var rnd= Math.floor(Math.random()*numbers.length),

    tmp= numbers[rnd];
    numbers[rnd]= numbers[i];
    numbers[i]= tmp;
  }

  return numbers;
} //randomize
```

For your example, you would call it like this:

```
numbers = randomize(0, 17, 2);
```

[**Fiddle 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/5up1jvpm/1/)

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to leave the array flexible to different number combination, dynamically.